# Create filter window similar to excels when pulling data from ODBC connection

Tags: java, filter, jpanel

So I have been having some troubles with the code on how to create the filter window on the right. You may find a screenshot of the window I am attempting to recreate here:

[Window Example](https://help.tallysolutions.com/docs/td9rel54/integration_capabilities/images/through_excel_3.gif)

So the left handed part of the window which holds the columns chosen is working perfectly. However, I can't figure out how to code the container for the right window. I have attempted a JScrollPane, but failed to add the text boxes correctly. It kept trying to make me add them as headers, rows, the main field, and more. I then tried adding a JPanel to the main JPanel holding the whole window, but I am unable to figure out how to add a scroll bar to the filter JPanel as well as looking on google for the answer.

The reason for the scroll bar is because I plan on adding more filter options than the window will allow. So the container that will be used for the filter options will need to be scrollable to allow for those additional filter options to be used.

I hope that this helps. I am not partial to any specific solution as I honestly don't know which one will fulfill what I am looking to do. I hope was able to provide enough detail. I am unable to provide code at this point as I am not near the project and there is so much code to show. If any clarity is needed, I will definitely do so. Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: First, start with getting a single filter row to work.  This would include the operation, and/or radio buttons and the text to be used.  Once you can get that to work, and produce filterable results from it, you can move onto to multiplying it.  This would then require to investigate different layout manager options, maybe something like `GridBagLayout` or, if you don't mind third party libraries, `VerticalLayout`

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer for the suggestions. I have the logic already played out how I am going to use the filters to create my results. I am just literally struggling with how to handle the layout. I am concerned with changing my layout in general to have to figure out how to recode it to how I have it setup now.. However, if you are meaning a different layout inside of a jPanel inside of the main JPanel, then I might have to try that. However, I am still at the point of no scroll bar. If you have a suggestion as to how to do that, I am open to it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes - use a “master” panel, onto which you add other panels, which hold controls for a single query

Comment: Alright. What about the scroll bar piece. I can do the master and slave panels. However, I am not sure how to handle the scroll bar piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Wrap the master panel in a `JScrollPane`

Comment: Alright. Let me try that out and see what happens. I will update you as soon as I test it out.